# API Gateway logs not showing up with terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to add CloudWatch logging to my API Gateway and have followed [posts like this one](https://medium.com/rockedscience/api-gateway-logging-with-terraform-d13f7701ed0b) to create the following terraform:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_api_gateway" {
  name = "${var.name}-api-gateway-role"
  description = "custom IAM Limited Role created with \"APIGateway\" as the trusted entity"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  tags = var.resourceTags
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "api_gateway_log_group" {
  name              = "/aws/lambda/${var.name}-api-gateway"
  retention_in_days = 14
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "api_gateway_logging" {
  name        = "${var.name}-api-gateway-logging"
  path        = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging from the api gateway"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "logs:GetLogEvents",
        "logs:FilterLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "gateway_logs" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam_for_api_gateway.id
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.api_gateway_logging.arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "root_api" {
  name = "${var.name}-rest-api-service"

  tags = var.resourceTags
}

# at this point there are various resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api" blocks, etc

resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "demo" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.iam_for_api_gateway.arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
  stage_name    = var.envName
  
  depends_on    = [
    aws_cloudwatch_log_group.api_gateway_log_group,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lang_integration,
    aws_api_gateway_account.demo
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
  stage_name  = var.envName
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "ERROR"
  }
}
```

But I am seeing no log entries generated for my API Gateway, though the log group is created.

I was previously getting this error:

```
Error: updating API Gateway Stage failed: BadRequestException: CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging

  on ..\2-sub-modules\e-api-gateway\main.tf line 627, in resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "example":
 627: resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "example" {
```

But then I updated the `resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "example"` block (as shown above).

Now, I don't get the above error, but I also don't get any API Gateway logs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi! Quick question, when you say that you don't get any API Gateway logs, do you see at least the log group created in cloudwatch?

Comment: Yes, I get the cloud watch log group.

Comment: Ok, an another silly question (just to understand the whole scenario) you are setting `logging_level   = "ERROR"` are you testing a KO scenario against that endpoint? Otherwise try setting up logging level to INFO and try again.

Comment: I've just checked the [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method_settings#logging_level) and possibly my understanding of the `logging_level` was the wrong way round. Perhaps, if I want "everything going through the API to be logged" I should be using `INFO`?

Comment: From the AWS [docummentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/1.0/APIReference/API_AwsApiGatewayMethodSettings.html) `If the logging level is INFO, then the logs include both ERROR events and extra informational events.` depending of what information do you want to extract, that log level could match your requeriments

Answer (score 10):

To fix the issue with "CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging" you should specify this role in API Gateway Account Settigns:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "demo" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudwatch" {
  name = "api_gateway_cloudwatch_global"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Details: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_account

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the information I provided in the comments, I would like to give a more precise answer to the question about why the logs are not displayed and how to display them in case someone runs into the same problem in the future.

With the `logging_level` property set to `ERROR` only the  errors will be displayed in cloudwatch.

If we want to log all the request going through the gateway we have to use `logging_level = "INFO"`. In order to display all the information related to the request like request URI, request headers, request body... we have to activate the `data_trace_enabled` property:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "example" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.root_api.id
  stage_name  = var.envName
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    data_trace_enabled = true
    metrics_enabled    = true
    logging_level      = "ERROR"
  }
}
```

Terraform `data_trace_enabled` property matches with the `Enable Detailed CloudWatch Metrics` property from the AWS API Gateway console:

[image: API Gateway]

Currently there is a known limitation in the API Gateway and all the [logs events larger than 1024bytes are truncated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html) so keep that in mind if expect calls with many headers or large bodies.

> API Gateway currently limits log events to 1024 bytes. Log events larger than 1024 bytes, such as request and response bodies, will be truncated by API Gateway before submission to CloudWatch Logs.